# PHPBB SQL query almost correct

Tags: php, sql, phpbb

In PHPBB I'm trying to edit an SQL to get some more data, which I can use in the posts.  The standard query grabs data from 3 tables (user_table, post_table and zebra_table).  For each row (post), it assigns the data to variables which can be used through the PHPBB html file, for example:

```
'username'          => $row['username'],
```

So in the HTML file, you can use {postrow.USERNAME}, and it will display the username of the current loop/post.

The standard query looks like this:

```
$sql = $db->sql_build_query('SELECT', array(
'SELECT'    => 'u.*, z.friend, z.foe, p.*',

'FROM'      => array(
    USERS_TABLE     => 'u',
    POSTS_TABLE     => 'p',
),

'LEFT_JOIN' => array(
    array(
        'FROM'  => array(ZEBRA_TABLE => 'z'),
        'ON'    => 'z.user_id = ' . $user->data['user_id'] . ' AND z.zebra_id = p.poster_id'
    )
),

'WHERE'     => $db->sql_in_set('p.post_id', $post_list) . '
    AND u.user_id = p.poster_id'
```

));

I am trying to pull the "pf_lol_summoner" value from the "phpbb_profile_fields_data" table, depending on what "user_id" it is currently on:

```
$sql = $db->sql_build_query('SELECT', array(
    'SELECT'        => 'u.*, pf.pf_lol_summoner, z.friend, z.foe, p.*',

    'FROM'          => array(
            USERS_TABLE             => 'u',
            POSTS_TABLE             => 'p',
    ),
    'LEFT_JOIN'     => array(
            array(
                    'FROM'  => array(ZEBRA_TABLE => 'z'),
                    'ON'    => 'z.user_id = ' . $user->data['user_id'] . ' AND z.zebra_id = p.poster_id'
            ),
            array(
                    'FROM'  => array('phpbb_profile_fields_data' => 'pf'),
                    'ON'    => 'pf.user_id = ' . $user->data['user_id']
            )
    ),
    'WHERE'         => $db->sql_in_set('p.post_id', $post_list) . '
            AND u.user_id = p.poster_id'
```

));

now when the while loop starts to loop through the rows, if I echo out:

```
echo $row['pf_lol_summoner'];
```

It displays my "pf_lol_summoner" value for each post, instead of each individuals value.  I think its using my user_id (which is set in a cookie).  Anyone notice anything?

EDIT: echo $row['username']; works fine, along with all the other values.

Comment: you restrict your `phpbb_profile_fields_data` table to just records for the user `$user->data['user_id']` - is that what you want to do?

Comment: Well the "phpbb_profile_fields_data" has two columns: user_id & pf_lol_summoner.  So I was trying to say, whatever the "user_id" is for this post, look for it in the phpbb_profile_fields_data table and give whatever value pf_lol_summoner has. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: yes, that is what it is doing, so you should be getting the correct results. have you checked your results against what is in the database? why do you think there is a problem, and what is the problem?

Comment: Ah, I know what is happening, just I can't work it out.  So $user->data['user_id'] gets the ID of the person loading the page. So my user_id = 1.  I'm saying get the pf.pf_lol_summoner where the user_id is mine, rather than the current poster_id.   If there is 3 posts on the page, it displays my pf.pf_lol_summoner each time.

Comment: where is "your" user_id defined? simply replace `'pf.user_id = ' . $user->data['user_id']` with `'pf.user_id = ' . $the_var_that_has_my_user_id`

Comment: 'ON'    => 'pf.user_id = p.poster_id'  Seems that was all it took, sorry for being stupid!

Comment: good! it wasn't an answer, but I'll take an upvote on my comment anytime ;)